# How in 'make' check the current operating system is?

Tags: makefile

I have two different options in gcc.
In linux is one in Mac other

How check in makefile what system current is?
  Windows, Linux, or OSX

Comment: There's nothing built-in to make for this. You get to run whatever tests you want to make that determination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple add this in Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
 OPCJE = -Wall -Wno-unused-const-variable
else
 OPCJE = -Wall
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in shell commands such as uname (on Unix systems) and parse the output. There's no built in functionality for it.

Comment: this answer is not for my question. it dependence of system. I compile my program in different systems

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this with the intention of distributing software, then rather than tweak Makefiles internally (there is no good solution to this; I wouldn't even try), you should investigate a build system which allows users to configure the build dynamically.

The most common mechanism for that is [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html).  Autoconf is a little tricky to get started with – there's a non-trivial learning curve, but it's in reality somewhat simpler than it looks at first – but it has the advantage that use of autoconf is very widespread.  If people are building a bit of software from source, they're rarely surprised to see a `configure` script, at which point their fingers automatically tap out `./configure; make; make install`.

The [Wikipedia page on autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) actually makes it look rather harder than it is, because the diagram displays the full-blown autoconf+automake+autoheader+aclocal ecosystem (what, they missed out `libtool`?!).  That page also rather goes to town on its ‘Criticism’ of autoconf.  While none of the points it makes are actually *false*, their importance is rather overstated.